# Excel 2010 autopopulate information without dragging columns down

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have raw data on one worksheet and another worksheet populated in specific columns with a formula to pull the data  or to do specific things. Is there a way to have this data auto populate without having to drag the column down to fill it on the 2nd sheet.

In other words, Column A on sheet 1 has 95 rows and column C references A on worksheet 1, but I need it to auto populate all 95 rows. I have over 100 columns that reference and cross reference...I just need it to be automated.

the only thing that will change is the raw data and the size of it....

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Enter or fill your formulas into the first row of all your columns.  Then select your entire array by clicking the top left cell containing a formula, and then shift-clicking the bottom right cell, 95 rows down.
2. Select "Fill > Down" from the Edit menu.